# Azure graph api returning different token each time a login attempt is made.?

Tags: python, azure, access-token

I have a python api which accepts `email` and `password` from a login webpage. This email and password is used to login to azure ad and in response we get a access token which is valid for `1hr`. Below is the sample python code:

```
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(config_data['AUTHORITY_HOST_URL'] + '/' + config_data['TENANT'], validate_authority="cceaddik-1q7c5-997ad-6453-sduf9347asit8" != 'adfs')

token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(config_data['RESOURCE'], email, password, config_data['CLIENT_ID'])

print(token['accessToken'])
```

Normally this token generated for a user should be valid for 1hr and if same user is logging again within the same 1hr, it should get the same access token. But what I have noticed is that, each time we login, we are getting different access token. Why is this happening. Can anyone please throw some lights on it. Thanks.

Comment: "anyone who is logging again within the same 1hr, it should get the same access token" why would you think that?

Comment: @HongOoi My applogies. I didnt mean anyone, I mean the same user is logging again within 1hr. I have update the question. Thanks

Comment: When you get a new token that is valid for an hour, it means the exp timestamp changes. If you login at 10:00 it expires at 11:00, if you login again at 10:05, it expires at 11:05 -> different exp -> different token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will always get a new token when you call Azure AD. It does not cache tokens there.
A token is valid for one hour from the time you requested the token.

As a side note, handling passwords is a bad idea in general.
It would be much better to use one of the interactive login flows like authorization code flow.
You cannot enable MFA for users for example, as the login would fail.

Comment: Is there any way to validate token if its valid or expired?

Comment: Yes. You can find a standard JWT validation library for Python and use it. I would not recommend you do it manually. If you did it manually, you need to validate the digital signature, the expiration and not before claims, the audience claim, the issuer claim and scopes/roles.